# PHP cURL, it's not fetching the desired page and instead fetches a cookie settings page

Tags: php, curl

Like the title says, this is really weird, this is supposed to fetch the page below but it instead only fetches the "cookie settings page".

My code:

```
<?php

// Set the URL of the webpage 
//visit this in your browswer to see the actual page
$url = "https://arbetsformedlingen.se/platsbanken/annonser/26981350";

// Set the cookie jar file
$cookie_jar = "cookies.txt";

// Set the form data
$form_data = array(
    'search-input' => '26981350'
);

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set the user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36");

// Set the cookie jar file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);

// Set the cookie file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);

// Set the form data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);

// Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Return the response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Print the content of the webpage
echo $content;

?>
```

Any ideas on getting the actual page? Been banging my head on this with no results :(

Answer (score 0):

Following is full code per your comment which did print the content, notice I made two changes to your code, comment out the post and http_build_query rest is same as you posted

```
// Set the URL of the webpage 
//visit this in your browswer to see the actual page
$url = "https://arbetsformedlingen.se/platsbanken/annonser/26981350";

// Set the cookie jar file
$cookie_jar = "cookies.txt";

// Set the form data
$form_data = array(
    'search-input' => '26981350'
);

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set the user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36");

// Set the cookie jar file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);

// Set the cookie file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);

// Set the form data
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($form_data));

// Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Return the response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Print the content of the webpage
echo $content;
```

Comment: I commented out the line but it still is not showing the page, is it working for you?

Comment: I updated my answer you also need to use http_build_query with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: Didn't work :( Maybe something is missing?

Comment: @Ryan it did work for me page was fetched successfully

Comment: Please post your full code, it's not working for me...

Comment: @Ryan I have updated my answer to include full code, notice I made only two changes to your code as I did my initial answer

Comment: Nope, still shows the cookie page...